# SVG or PNG for html5 android game?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, svg, png

I created html5 android game. It uses simple ball which is device motion moved. For moving ball I use setinterval in javascript and change position for ball element.

So what is better to use for better rendering and perfomance? SVG or PNG ball? And other elements in game, like coins, lifes etc.

It seems like game is much smoother if i run it in chrome browser on mobile (android 5.0.2) then in webview. I use phonegap build and set miniandroid sdk level 19. (4.4), because i read that webview in 4.4 uses chromium engine.

For my game i use svg for all elemnts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer using `<canvas>` for HTML5 games since it is hardware accelerated. You shouldn't use png's since having to move a lot of them at the same time can be very costly/slow.

The downside to this is that you will have to create all object management methods/eventhandlers yourself (onclick, onmouseover etc.) or use a game engine which already implements all of this.

Anyhow if you're going with either plain html elements or svg, I would go with svg.